# mypy: how to write type hints for a function that takes 2 positional arguments but it is enough that only 1 is passed?

Tags: python, mypy

Say that I have a function `foo` such that it is allowed to take arguments as it follows

```
foo(a,b) -> It is OK
foo(None,b) -> It is OK
foo (a, None) -> It is OK
foo(None,None) -> It is NOT OK!!!
```

How to write its signature, including its type hints?

At the moment I have written the type hints as

```
def foo(a:Optional[str], b:Optional[str]) -> str
```

but that is wrong because such signature would be fine with the call `foo(None,None)`.

Comment: IMO, `Optional[Any]` is no different from `Any`. Unfortunately, Python does not have anything similar to `Not[None]`.

Comment: `Any` matches `None`, so there isn't any difference between `Any` and `Optional[Any]`.  If you have actual types for `a` and `b` you can do this with `@overload` but annotating with `Any` types is essentially the same as not doing type checking.

Comment: Ok, I updated the question, to be more specific.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`@overload`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.overload) to define different (narrower) signatures for a function.  Mypy will check calls to that function against all the overloaded signatures and produce an error if none of them match.

```
from typing import overload, Optional

@overload
def foo(a: str, b: Optional[str]) -> str: ...

@overload
def foo(a: Optional[str], b: str) -> str: ...

def foo(a: Optional[str], b: Optional[str]) -> str:
    return (a or "") + (b or "")

foo('a', 'b') 
foo(None, 'b')
foo ('a', None)
foo(None, None)  # error: No overload variant of "foo" matches argument types "None", "None"
```